# CABasicAnimation on property not animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cabasicanimation

I made a piechart class and now got stuck trying to animate it.
Found this: https://github.com/pavanpodila/PieChart
I have tried to implement the animation part off it but can't get the animation to work.

When the piechart view is added there is no visible pie slices for the duration set in:
`makeAnimationForKey:` in PieChartLayer.m

But after the duration the slices are drawn.
So now it basically works like a delay for showing it which isn't intended :)

Everything else works like it should.

Tried to fiddle around with a bunch of hacks...

### PieSlice creation method

```
- (PieSliceLayer *)filledCirleWithStartAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle withColor:(UIColor *)color {

PieSliceLayer *layer = [PieSliceLayer layer];
layer.frame = self.frame;
layer.fillColor = color;
layer.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];
layer.center = center;
layer.radius = radius;
layer.startAngle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle);
layer.endAngle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(endAngle);

return layer;
}
```

### PieSliceLayer

```
#import "PieSliceLayer.h"

@implementation PieSliceLayer
@dynamic startAngle, endAngle;
@synthesize fillColor, strokeColor, strokeWidth;

- (CABasicAnimation *)makeAnimationForKey:(NSString *)key {
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:key];
anim.fromValue = [[self presentationLayer] valueForKey:key];
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
anim.duration = 0.9f;

return anim;
}

- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.strokeWidth = 0;
    
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

return self;
}

-(id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event {
if ([event isEqualToString:@"startAngle"] ||
    [event isEqualToString:@"endAngle"]) {
    return [self makeAnimationForKey:event];
}

return [super actionForKey:event];
}

- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer {
if (self = [super initWithLayer:layer]) {
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:[PieSliceLayer class]]) {
        PieSliceLayer *other = (PieSliceLayer *)layer;
        self.startAngle = other.startAngle;
        self.endAngle = other.endAngle;
        self.fillColor = other.fillColor;
        
        self.strokeColor = other.strokeColor;
        self.strokeWidth = other.strokeWidth;
    }
}

return self;
}

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
if ([key isEqualToString:@"startAngle"] || [key isEqualToString:@"endAngle"]) {
    return YES;
}

return [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}


-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {

// Create the path
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
CGFloat radius = self.radius;

CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, center.x, center.y);

CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(center.x + radius * cosf(self.startAngle), center.y + radius * sinf(self.startAngle));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, p1.x, p1.y);

int clockwise = self.startAngle > self.endAngle;
CGContextAddArc(ctx, center.x, center.y, radius, self.startAngle, self.endAngle, clockwise);

CGContextClosePath(ctx);

// Color it
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, self.fillColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, self.strokeColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, self.strokeWidth);

CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

@end
```

Comment: You're not setting toValue in makeAnimation.

Comment: It's being set with start and endAngle.

Answer (score 1):

In your initWithLayer method you forgot to set the radius.

```
self.radius = other.radius;
```